# After migration: Ruby code sees method as undefined, ran fine previously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

So my Odyssey of fixing a [broken ruby setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/501476/ruby-mongrel-installation-broken-after-centos-upgrade-server-wont-start) is not yet quite over. 
I'm now running a passenger server, and ruby 1.8.7 with rails 2.2.2, since there's a legacy installation that requires it. This installation now works - partially. Some parts do not, and this is the error message I get in production.log:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `textilize' for #<ActionView::Base:0x7fa9369fb9d8>) on line #3 of app/views/static/partners.rhtml:
1: <div id ="title"><h6>Partners</h6><br></div>
2: <div id="content_left">
3: <p><%= textilize(Static.find(:first, :conditions => [ "title = 'Partners'"]).text) %></p>
4: <br>
5: </div>
```

As you can see that's some custom code which for some reason sees a method as "undefined". I've copied everything over from an installation that was previously working, so I wonder how that could have happened. It spurts out some more errors which I've dumped [here](http://pastie.org/7698543).

Comment: Ask the app developer.

Comment: Probably you have installed different versions of gems - compare `gem list` on old and new servers.

Comment: I only have a backup of the old server, so can't run any commands on it. What file could I check to see the environment that was active?

Answer (score 0):

After AlexD's comment I looked a bit more. The solution was to install [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org), that was the gem that was missing.